# Edit limited to part of multi geometry collection in kml google earth

Tags: kml, google-earth, line

I have polylines on kml format ,I want to edit those kml polylines via google earth when I try to modify the polyline I get the error Edit limited to part of multi geometry collection.

Comment: This [site](http://docslide.us/documents/google-earth-error-messages.html) has in formation in the Transcript section : "Edit limited to part of Multi Geometry collection - You are You're trying to edit multiple polygons or paths at the Feature trying to edit a collection of same time. Please select a single polygon or path to edit es geometry items. Only editing of and continue. the first item will be possible. Google Earth Plus can only import up to 100 features at a time. Please check the number of features in your Google Earth Notice/Google Featur CSC/TXT file and try again"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to edit your polylines (KML Multigeometries) in Google Earth... it's not set up for that. If you're a GIS person, or willing to learn, you should be able to import the KML(s) into QGIS, convert the combined geometries into individual geometries (separate features, whether lines or polygons).  Then you can either export back to KML for editing in Google Earth, or do the edits with QGIS' powerful editing tools and then export back to KML for viewing in Earth.